# Search for references of a view in MSSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We have a huge database, let's call it TestDB for convenience and I'm supposed to look if *anything* within that database references a view, VTest.

I have absolutely no experience with SQL and all I could find referred to looking for things in table columns, which isn't exactly helping a whole lot.

How would one go about solving this, aside from manually looking through every single file.

Comment: Check out INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: Right click on the view in the Object Explorer, `View Dependencies`. This works with any object not just views and shows *transient* dependencies as well

Answer (score 0):

I have used this script for searching through SPs for years, there is probably a better way, but it works:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME() [DB_Name], 
        SCHEMA_NAME(p.[schema_id]) [Schema], 
        p.Name, p.type_desc, 
        p.create_date, 
        p.modify_date, 
        p.object_id, 
        p.schema_id
FROM    sys.procedures p
WHERE   OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%VTest%'
ORDER BY 2,3
```